# Neo4j console returning only 1000 rows

Tags: neo4j

I would like to compare mysql and neo4j and for that I have dumped a lot of data in neo4j as well mysql.

now the problem is In neo4j I cannot execute a query which returns more than 1000 rows therefore I cannot see the time of execution of that query.

In mysql I can eaily see the execution time in the console.

Also I would like to see a complete graphical view of all my nodes in Neo4j. Is it possible?

Comment: For those comparisons you should never use the web-browser as the timings it takes include many roundtrips and additional data loading. Use the console instead: http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/

Answer (score 2):

The limitation to 1000 result is a safety net withing Neo4j browser. Otherwise very long results might mess up your web browser in terms of memory and/or CPU for rendering.

To get the full plain results for comparison send your query as REST request using e.g. cURL. See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request for an example of the request, make sure you're using `Accept` and `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`. Additionally you might stream the result as documented at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-streaming.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting that limits the number of rows displayed, by default it's 1000. To change this setting Open Neo4j Browser -> Go to **Settings** and in the Graph Visualization section you can find `Max Rows`. You can change this to fit your needs. Also in this section another property can be found `Initial Node Display` - property that limit number of nodes displayed on the first load of the graph visualization.